# Datastax Spark: Job failed on Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, datastax, datastax-enterprise, apache-zeppelin

I have set up Datastax Enterprice in three nodes in the local network.
Two nodes are debian servers and i used `apt` package manager for installation. The last node is iMac and i used the `.dmg` package for installation.

```
Node #1:
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 8.10 (jessie)
Local IP: 172.16.21.18
Datastax Enterprice: 5.1.7

Node #2:
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Local IP: 172.16.21.25
Datastax Enterprice: 5.1.7

Node #1:
OS: macOS 10.13.2
Local IP: 192.168.1.108
Datastax Enterprice: 5.1.7
```

Nodes are up and running in analytics and search mode: (`$ dse cassandra -k -s`)
[image: spark cluster webui]
Now, I'm trying to connect on Spark Cluster using Apache Zeppelin **0.7.3**. Apache Zeppelin is installed and configured in Node #1.

I followed [these](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005936066-How-To-Use-Apache-Zeppelin-with-DSE-Spark-on-DSE-5-0-x-and-4-8-x) instructions for configuration. Below you can see some basic changes in config files:

zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/conf/zeppelin-env.sh

```
[..]
export MASTER=spark://172.16.21.18:7077                                 # Spark master url. eg. spark://master_addr:7077. Leave empty if you want to use local mode.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export DSE_HOME=/usr
[..]
```

zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/bin/interpreter.sh

```
[..]
# set spark related env variables
if [[ "${INTERPRETER_ID}" == "spark" ]]; then
  if [[ -n "${SPARK_HOME}" ]]; then
    export SPARK_SUBMIT="${DSE_HOME}/bin/dse spark-submit"
[..]
```

Zeppelin Spark Intepreter:

[image]

Zeppelin CQL intepreter works perfect with Apache Cassandra but then i'm trying to use Spark Intepreter to execute some queries i'm getting this error:

```
%spark
val results = spark.sql("SELECT * from keyspace.table")

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
    [..]
```

complete zeppelin log file:

```
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:36,185] ({Thread-0} RemoteInterpreterServer.java[run]:97) - Starting remote interpreter server on port 52127
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:36,562] ({pool-1-thread-3} RemoteInterpreterServer.java[createInterpreter]:198) - Instantiate interpreter org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:36,589] ({pool-1-thread-3} RemoteInterpreterServer.java[createInterpreter]:198) - Instantiate interpreter org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkSqlInterpreter
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:36,601] ({pool-1-thread-3} RemoteInterpreterServer.java[createInterpreter]:198) - Instantiate interpreter org.apache.zeppelin.spark.DepInterpreter
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:36,619] ({pool-1-thread-3} RemoteInterpreterServer.java[createInterpreter]:198) - Instantiate interpreter org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:36,622] ({pool-1-thread-3} RemoteInterpreterServer.java[createInterpreter]:198) - Instantiate interpreter org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkRInterpreter
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:36,683] ({pool-2-thread-2} SchedulerFactory.java[jobStarted]:131) - Job remoteInterpretJob_1519205136682 started by scheduler org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter269729544
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:40,733] ({pool-2-thread-2} SparkInterpreter.java[createSparkSession]:318) - ------ Create new SparkContext spark://172.16.21.18:7077 -------
 WARN [2018-02-21 04:25:40,740] ({pool-2-thread-2} SparkInterpreter.java[setupConfForSparkR]:577) - sparkr.zip is not found, sparkr may not work.
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:40,786] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Running Spark version 2.1.0
 WARN [2018-02-21 04:25:41,760] ({pool-2-thread-2} NativeCodeLoader.java[<clinit>]:62) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
 WARN [2018-02-21 04:25:41,958] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logWarning]:66) - 
SPARK_CLASSPATH was detected (set to ':/home/cassandra/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/interpreter/spark/dep/*:/home/cassandra/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/interpreter/spark/*:/home/cassandra/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/lib/interpreter/*:').
This is deprecated in Spark 1.0+.

Please instead use:
 - ./spark-submit with --driver-class-path to augment the driver classpath
 - spark.executor.extraClassPath to augment the executor classpath

 WARN [2018-02-21 04:25:41,959] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logWarning]:66) - Setting 'spark.executor.extraClassPath' to ':/home/cassandra/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/interpreter/spark/dep/*:/home/cassandra/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/interpreter/spark/*:/home/cassandra/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/lib/interpreter/*:' as a work-around.
 WARN [2018-02-21 04:25:41,960] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logWarning]:66) - Setting 'spark.driver.extraClassPath' to ':/home/cassandra/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/interpreter/spark/dep/*:/home/cassandra/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/interpreter/spark/*:/home/cassandra/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/lib/interpreter/*:' as a work-around.
 WARN [2018-02-21 04:25:41,986] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logWarning]:66) - Your hostname, XPLAIN005 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 172.16.21.18 instead (on interface eth0)
 WARN [2018-02-21 04:25:41,987] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logWarning]:66) - Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,017] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Changing view acls to: cassandra
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,017] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Changing modify acls to: cassandra
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,018] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Changing view acls groups to: 
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,019] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Changing modify acls groups to: 
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,019] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(cassandra); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(cassandra); groups with modify permissions: Set()
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,417] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 51240.
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,445] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Registering MapOutputTracker
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,476] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Registering BlockManagerMaster
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,481] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,482] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,507] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-797ea400-69f1-4228-a6da-fe424edce8d4
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,524] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - MemoryStore started with capacity 408.9 MB
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,591] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,700] ({pool-2-thread-2} Log.java[initialized]:186) - Logging initialized @6930ms
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,864] ({pool-2-thread-2} Server.java[doStart]:327) - jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,902] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2cbd702d{/jobs,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,903] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@240b993c{/jobs/json,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,903] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5b7d8292{/jobs/job,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,908] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4c2353ff{/jobs/job/json,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,909] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@bd87e4e{/stages,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,910] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@73e2d470{/stages/json,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,917] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@44bca18c{/stages/stage,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,918] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1256be4f{/stages/stage/json,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,919] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5a349845{/stages/pool,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,919] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3f108627{/stages/pool/json,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,926] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1e01f088{/storage,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,927] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@390281c1{/storage/json,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,927] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@470ac014{/storage/rdd,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,927] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7c90476c{/storage/rdd/json,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,928] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6d847dc6{/environment,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,936] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@40a5e53e{/environment/json,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,937] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@513e975e{/executors,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,937] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2f6b1132{/executors/json,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,938] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@61cf2354{/executors/threadDump,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,939] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eacb646{/executors/threadDump/json,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,951] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2b8d44aa{/static,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,953] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5c982268{/,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,954] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@44556f2c{/api,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,955] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2fa0ef66{/jobs/job/kill,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,955] ({pool-2-thread-2} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6e49562c{/stages/stage/kill,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,970] ({pool-2-thread-2} AbstractConnector.java[doStart]:266) - Started ServerConnector@53405611{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4040}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,971] ({pool-2-thread-2} Server.java[doStart]:379) - Started @7201ms
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,971] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:42,974] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://172.16.21.18:4040
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:43,214] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Added file file:/home/cassandra/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/interpreter/spark/pyspark/pyspark.zip at spark://172.16.21.18:51240/files/pyspark.zip with timestamp 1519205143214
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:43,217] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Copying /home/cassandra/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/interpreter/spark/pyspark/pyspark.zip to /tmp/spark-2e9292e3-8c4d-445a-92f0-7d54188818db/userFiles-4e8301a5-91bc-4753-8436-6cced0bdc5c5/pyspark.zip
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:43,226] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Added file file:/home/cassandra/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/interpreter/spark/pyspark/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip at spark://172.16.21.18:51240/files/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip with timestamp 1519205143226
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:43,227] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Copying /home/cassandra/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/interpreter/spark/pyspark/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip to /tmp/spark-2e9292e3-8c4d-445a-92f0-7d54188818db/userFiles-4e8301a5-91bc-4753-8436-6cced0bdc5c5/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:43,279] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Created default pool default, schedulingMode: FIFO, minShare: 0, weight: 1
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:43,325] ({appclient-register-master-threadpool-0} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Connecting to master spark://172.16.21.18:7077...
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:25:43,391] ({netty-rpc-connection-0} TransportClientFactory.java[createClient]:250) - Successfully created connection to /172.16.21.18:7077 after 33 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:03,326] ({appclient-register-master-threadpool-0} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Connecting to master spark://172.16.21.18:7077...
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:23,326] ({appclient-register-master-threadpool-0} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Connecting to master spark://172.16.21.18:7077...
ERROR [2018-02-21 04:26:43,328] ({appclient-registration-retry-thread} Logging.scala[logError]:70) - Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
 WARN [2018-02-21 04:26:43,328] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logWarning]:66) - Application ID is not initialized yet.
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,336] ({stop-spark-context} AbstractConnector.java[doStop]:306) - Stopped ServerConnector@53405611{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4040}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,339] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 40068.
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,498] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Server created on 172.16.21.18:40068
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,499] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6e49562c{/stages/stage/kill,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,500] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2fa0ef66{/jobs/job/kill,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,501] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@44556f2c{/api,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,501] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5c982268{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,505] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2b8d44aa{/static,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,506] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eacb646{/executors/threadDump/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,507] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@61cf2354{/executors/threadDump,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,508] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,508] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2f6b1132{/executors/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,509] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@513e975e{/executors,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,510] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@40a5e53e{/environment/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,511] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6d847dc6{/environment,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,511] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7c90476c{/storage/rdd/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,512] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@470ac014{/storage/rdd,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,513] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@390281c1{/storage/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,513] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1e01f088{/storage,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,513] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3f108627{/stages/pool/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,514] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 172.16.21.18, 40068, None)
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,514] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5a349845{/stages/pool,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,515] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1256be4f{/stages/stage/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,515] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@44bca18c{/stages/stage,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,516] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@73e2d470{/stages/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,516] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@bd87e4e{/stages,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,517] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4c2353ff{/jobs/job/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,517] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5b7d8292{/jobs/job,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,518] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@240b993c{/jobs/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,518] ({stop-spark-context} ContextHandler.java[doStop]:865) - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2cbd702d{/jobs,null,UNAVAILABLE}
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,521] ({dispatcher-event-loop-0} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Registering block manager 172.16.21.18:40068 with 408.9 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 172.16.21.18, 40068, None)
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,522] ({stop-spark-context} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Stopped Spark web UI at http://172.16.21.18:4040
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,526] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 172.16.21.18, 40068, None)
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,527] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 172.16.21.18, 40068, None)
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,530] ({stop-spark-context} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Shutting down all executors
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,546] ({dispatcher-event-loop-1} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Asking each executor to shut down
 WARN [2018-02-21 04:26:43,561] ({dispatcher-event-loop-0} Logging.scala[logWarning]:66) - Drop UnregisterApplication(null) because has not yet connected to master
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,583] ({dispatcher-event-loop-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,596] ({stop-spark-context} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - MemoryStore cleared
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,597] ({stop-spark-context} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - BlockManager stopped
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,605] ({stop-spark-context} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - BlockManagerMaster stopped
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,608] ({dispatcher-event-loop-1} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
ERROR [2018-02-21 04:26:43,748] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logError]:91) - Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:524)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkSession(SparkInterpreter.java:378)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkSession(SparkInterpreter.java:233)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:841)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:491)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,751] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - SparkContext already stopped.
ERROR [2018-02-21 04:26:43,751] ({pool-2-thread-2} Utils.java[invokeMethod]:40) - 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkSession(SparkInterpreter.java:378)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkSession(SparkInterpreter.java:233)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:841)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:491)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:524)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
    ... 20 more
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,752] ({stop-spark-context} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Successfully stopped SparkContext
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,752] ({pool-2-thread-2} SparkInterpreter.java[createSparkSession]:379) - Created Spark session
ERROR [2018-02-21 04:26:43,753] ({pool-2-thread-2} Job.java[run]:181) - Job failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext_2(SparkInterpreter.java:398)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:387)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:146)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:843)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:491)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 INFO [2018-02-21 04:26:43,759] ({pool-2-thread-2} SchedulerFactory.java[jobFinished]:137) - Job remoteInterpretJob_1519205136682 finished by scheduler org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter269729544
```

What do you think?

**UPDATE:**

All nodes upgraded to Datastax Enterprice **5.1.7**

Comment: I have exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With DSE 5.1 any reference to the Spark Master should look like this example:

export MASTER=dse://1.20.300.10

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR [2018-02-21 04:26:43,328] ({appclient-registration-retry-thread} Logging.scala[logError]:70) - Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
>    WARN [2018-02-21 04:26:43,328] ({pool-2-thread-2} Logging.scala[logWarning]:66) - Application ID is not initialized yet.

It seems the app is killed. Could you check the logs in spark master ?